# Webpage wont open on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def readScreens():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("close-icon")
    element.click()
    element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
```

when I run all it shows is this

> Franciscos-MBP:EBEC fran$ /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/fran/OneDrive
>
> - purdue.edu/Spring 2022/EBEC/wordle/readScreen.py"

I have vscode.

Comment: What do you expect to be displayed to you?

Comment: I wanted it to open the website in my computer, i do not know how it works :/

Comment: Do you have chrome driver installed?

Comment: I do, but I do not know if I have to set it up or anything